# Armature duplication for mirroring

Tags: armature

I can't figure out why some of my duplicated armatures do not show up in object mode after duplicating them in edit mode. I am currently rigging a humanoid mesh and all of the armatures are copied over except for the legs on one side.

[image]

However, they appear in edit mode.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution. Thank you!